# Why getting null in the request parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

Below is my API.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(IEnumerable<int> customerIds)
{
    //api stuff
}
```

But when this API is hit I am getting customerIds as null.

This is how I am calling the API via Postman.

```
{
 "customerIds" : [69,50]
}

Content-Type = application/json
```

However, if I update the API as below, values are caught.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(CustomerTO customerIds)
{
    //api stuff
}
public class CustomerTO
{
   public IEnumerable<int> CustomerIds
}
```

If I do so, I think its an overhead.

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: You are passing in an object that has a property called `customerIds`.  You need to pass in an array of integers instead, `[59,60]`.

Comment: Replace `CustomerTO customerIds` with `public IEnumerable<int> CustomerIds`

Comment: or in your json replace `"customerIds" : [69,50]` with "customerIds" : {"cutomerIds": [69,50]}

Comment: @Alex: replacing `CustomerTO customerIds` with `IEnumerable<int> CustomerIds` would just give you the original wouldn't it? Or are you thinking about replacing somewhere else (not sure where would work with the `public` keyword in there so tried to guess what you meant). Also I'm not even sure what you are thinking with the second comment. How would that help the simpler code work? Wouldn't it make it even worse?

Comment: @Chris,  my bad. didn't read the question carefully. @Kgn-web is the request an `HTTPDELETE` one?

Comment: @Alex, `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your post data object.
You just need to pass an array `[1,2,3,4]` in your request data.

Comment: But this not a valid json `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Why its not valid, i have tested it and working perfectly

Comment: Yes. my mistake. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one I think you might need to do it like this:

```
([FromBody] IEnumerable<int> customerIds)
```

Comment: [FromBody] attributes specifies from where the values are going to come from body or url. That's it

Comment: With this method you also need to send just the array through postman instead of the object.